# trouble understanding subsets and well ordered subsets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to understand what a subset is and would appreciate examples to develop intuition. I understand that a subset is a mini-set of the members of a container set. I'm working on problems related to "well ordered sets" where a set of numbers if well ordered when each of its nonempty subsets has a minimum element.

For example the problem asks to indicate which of the following sets of numbers have a minimum element and which are well ordered. For those that are not well ordered, give an example of a subset with no minimum element. I provided my answers and would appreciate if others could check my solutions.

*for the following problems I assume $n$ ranges over nonnegative integers unless otherwise specified.

a) integers greater than or equal to $-\sqrt{2}$:
For this set there would be a minimum ($-\sqrt{2}$ and any subset if well ordered since the subset would only contain integers. Therefore there will always be a least integer.

b) the rational numbers greater than or equal to $\sqrt{2}$
There will always be a minimum ($\sqrt{2}$). However a subset may not be well ordered because the subset contains rational numbers. For example, a silly subset would be rationals whose ones digit is a $0$. There would never be a smallest element since you could have $0.01$, $0.0001$, and so on.

c) The set of rationals of the form $\frac{1}{n}$ where $n$ is a positive integer.
There will never be a minimum because $n$'s range is infinite. A subset may not be well ordered because the subset could range to infinity. For example the subset could be n that are even only. However there are infinite positive n integers.

d) the set $G$ of rationals of the form $\frac{m}{n}$ where $m,n>0$ and $n \leq g$ where $g$ is a googol, $10^{100}$.
This set contains a minimum $\frac{1}{10^{100}}$. Any subset is well ordered because $n$ has an upper and lower bound. Also $m$ has a minimum where $m > 0$. Therefore these constraints require that any subset have a minimum.

e)The set $F$ of fractions of the form $\frac{n}{n+1}$:
This set has a minimum: $0$. Any subset is well ordered because the minimum element is the one with the least numerator.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is. Do you want feedback on your answers to a)-e)?

Comment: yeah sorry I clarified in the question that I'd like feedback.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure how to illuminate the notion of subset. A set is a collection of elements (at least in the naive point of view, which I think is where you should be thinking) and a subset is simply some subcollection: If your set is a jar with a bunch of little objects in it (say labelled pebbles) the a subset is just pouring some (possibly none or all) of them into another jar, but we can't just pick up a pebble that wasn't in the first jar and put it in the subset jar, anything in the subset jar has to have come from the first jar.

But a few things about well ordering: For a set to be well ordered means *every subset* of that set has a minimum. For example, let $S$ be the rationals greater than or equal to zero. $S$ has a minimum: $0$, but it is not well-ordered because if we remove zero then none of the remaining numbers is the smallest of those left (we could always just divide it in half to get something smaller).

So for $(a),(b)$ you need to be careful. $\sqrt{2}$ isn't a rational, and it certainly isnt an integer, thus it cannot be the min of the sets listed because *it isn't even in them*. What it is is a lower bound, but a minimum must be in the set.